# Apply recursive run to $com.GetDetailsOf to get length parameter

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a power-shell script to obtain the length (duration) attribute of .wav files saved in a folder.

While I can execute the below script to obtain the attributes, I can't get to run in a recursive more - that is, to look at .wav within subfolders.

Could someone please suggest the necessary updates?

```
$folder= 'C:\folder'

$com = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace($folder)
for($i = 0; $i -lt 64; $i++){
    $name = $com.GetDetailsOf($com.Items, $i)
    if ($name -eq 'Length') { $lengthattribute = $i}
}
$com.Items() |
    ForEach-Object{
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Name = $_.Name
            Path = $_.Path
            Size = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 1)
            DateCreated = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 4)
            Length = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, $lengthattribute)
            
        }
} | Export-Csv -Path $folder\length.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take the specified folder plus a recursive list of each subfolder and extract the info on only the wav files.

```
$folder= 'C:\folder'

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

@(Get-Item $folder) + @(Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory -Recurse) | ForEach-Object {
    $com = $shell.NameSpace($_.FullName)

    foreach($item in $com.Items() | Where-Object type -eq "WAV File")
    {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Name        = $item.Name
            Path        = $item.Path
            Size        = $com.GetDetailsOf($item, 1)
            DateCreated = $com.GetDetailsOf($item, 4)
            Length      = $com.GetDetailsOf($item, 27)
        
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

In the event that the files are named .wav but aren't actual wav files, either of these alternatives should work.

```
$folder= 'C:\folder'

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

@(Get-Item $folder) + @(Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory -Recurse) | ForEach-Object {
    $com = $shell.NameSpace($_.FullName)

    foreach($item in $com.Items() | Where-Object name -match '\.wav')
    {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Name        = $item.Name
            Path        = $item.Path
            Size        = $com.GetDetailsOf($item, 1)
            DateCreated = $com.GetDetailsOf($item, 4)
            Length      = $com.GetDetailsOf($item, 27)
    
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
$folder= 'C:\folder'

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

@(Get-Item $folder) + @(Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory -Recurse) | ForEach-Object {
    $com = $shell.NameSpace($_.FullName)

    foreach($item in $com.Items() | Where-Object name -like '*.wav')
    {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Name        = $item.Name
            Path        = $item.Path
            Size        = $com.GetDetailsOf($item, 1)
            DateCreated = $com.GetDetailsOf($item, 4)
            Length      = $com.GetDetailsOf($item, 27)
    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Doug. I can't seem to get any output from your script.

Comment: Then perhaps they aren’t actually wav files.

Answer (score 0):

modified the code you suggested in this way - and it works!

```
$folder= "C:\folder"

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

@(Get-Item $folder) + @(Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory -Recurse) | ForEach-Object {
    $com = $shell.NameSpace($_.FullName)

    foreach($item in $com.Items() | Where-Object **{ $_.Name -like "*.wav" }**)
    {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Name        = $item.Name
            Path        = $item.Path
            Size        = $com.GetDetailsOf($item, 1)
            DateCreated = $com.GetDetailsOf($item, 4)
            Length      = $com.GetDetailsOf($item, 27)
        
        }
    }
}**
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please delete this duplicate.